# How do I package (via RPM) a GStreamer element written in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpm, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

I seem to have reached an intersection point between all of the documentation that I can find, where what I want to do is covered by none of it.

I have written and tested a GStreamer element, written (mostly) in Python. I now need to package this for distribution as a .rpm file. I see contradictory information on how to build an rpm for a gstreamer element, how to package python code, and how to build an rpm in general.

I'm a newbie to both Python and building .rpm distributions although I have managed the latter for some of the gstreamer elements I've written in C.

The code I have is very simple. It consists of a single `my_element.py` file inside a `python` subdirectory inside the distribution but I have no idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Create `setup.py` and then continue with https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Python/#_example_python_spec_file